# SSRS Report timing out

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report on a customers site, pulling back monthly data. The query is quite intensive, and can take anywhere from 5 - 15 minutes to run. (longer as the month goes on, as it's processing everything from the current month)

The time taken isn't an issue with the customer. However, the problem is that the report times out after 10 minutes.

On the report sever I've ticked 'Do not timeout report' (site settings/general/Report Timeout).
[Do not timeout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K2n5.png)

In the code behind my report viewer I've set the following -
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Timeout = 1200000 i.e. 20 mins timeout

On the report dataset I've set it to not timeout i.e Dataset Properties/Query/Timeout in seconds set to 0.

But it still timesout in 10 minutes. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Timeout removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k18eF.png)

Comment: Can you do something to break up the processing of the report to a temp table and run the report from there? Maybe run a job overnight to aggregate the day's data into the table. May or may not work depending on your scenario, but the users may be OK with it.

Comment: Please post the text of error messages and configuration settings, not just images.

Answer (score 1):

I see you've already tried setting the ReportViewer Timeout value.  A few other things you can try:

Try updating the executionTimeout in httpRuntime in web.config (for example, C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.SQL2008\Reporting Services\ReportServer\web.config)

Try updating SQLCommandTimeoutSeconds in the Report Server configuration (e.g., C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.SQL2008\Reporting Services\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config)

Try looking at the SSRS logfiles (e.g., C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.SQL2008\Reporting Services\LogFiles) to figure out what's going on.